# How can I use the latest HttpComponents version on Android?

Tags: java, android, http, apache-httpcomponents

I was using the HttpComponents library that Android comes with. I wrote 2 classes to send params with GET and POST and to recieve an InputStream or a String from the server. All was working fine: every download on a thread, start, pause, resume... But today I've started two downloads simultaneously and none of them have finished.
I've googled a solution and I've seen that Android comes with HttpCore 4.0-beta2. Yes, it's very old. It was released on 01 July 2008 and Android hasn't updated it since then...
I've rewritten my classes but now using HttpURLConnection and I can download two files at the same time.
OK, that was a warning for you if you are considering using HttpComponents on Android. Now my question. I want to import the new version 4.1 to my project. I've added the jars to the built path, but now how can I use these jars if the new (4.1) and the old (beta2, 4.0) packages are the same?
Thanks.
**SOLVED**
You have to create the DefaultHttpCLinet with a ThreadSafeClientConnManager:

```
HttpParams parameters = new BasicHttpParams ();
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion (parameters, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset (parameters, HTTP.UTF_8);
HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue (parameters, false);
ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections (parameters, MAX_CONNECTIONS);

SchemeRegistry schReg = new SchemeRegistry ();
schReg.register (new Scheme ("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory (), 80));

client = new DefaultHttpClient (new ThreadSafeClientConnManager (parameters, schReg), parameters);
```

**UPDATE**: You can also use AndroidHttpClient. With this class you don't need to use ThreadSafeClientConnManager

```
AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance ("Android");
```

[More info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But today I've started two downloads simultaneously none of them finished.

Because HttpClient is not thread-safe by default. You have to hook up a `ThreadSafeClientConnManager` for that. This is covered in the [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientMultiThreadedExecution.java) documentation.

> I've googled a solution and I've seen that Android comes with HttpCore 4.0-beta2. Yes, it's very old. It was released on 01 July 2008 and Android hasn't updated it since then... and it's BUGGED

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/apache-http

Please notice that there are quite a few commits since "01 July 2008".

> I've rewritten my classes but now using HttpURLConnection and I can download two files at the same time.

Most programmers can do this with HttpClient as well.

> how can I use these jars if the new (4.1) and the old (beta2, 4.0) packages are the same?

You can't.

Comment: Thanks, but the example you have provided is for the 4.1 version. The solution is in my the post.